# Cannot install module mymodule. Unfortunately, the module did not return additional details

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am new in Prestashop module development.
I am trying to build amy first prestashop module[ref: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module].
Here is my code

```
<?php
    if(!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
        exit();
    class MyModule extends Module
    {
        public function _construct()
        {
            $this->name = 'mymodule';
            $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
            $this->version = '1.0.0';
            $this->author = 'Rohit Prakash';
            $this->need_instance = 0;
            $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
            $this->bootstrap = true;

            parent::__construct();

            $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
            $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

            $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

            if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))      
              $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
        }

        public function install()
        {
          if (!parent::install())
            return false;
          return true;
        }

        public function uninstall()
        {
          if (!parent::uninstall())
            return false;
          return true;
        }
    }
```

when I am trying to install mymodule from back office then got an error message

"Error!
Cannot install module mymodule. Unfortunately, the module did not return additional details."

help me please!!

Answer (score 1):

you have an error. instead of the `_construct()` it should be `__construct()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late here but this worked for my case.

- First, delete the last row from module table.

  If table prefix is `ps` and your module name is `mymodule`, it will be stored in `ps_module` table with column `name` value `mymodule`.

```
DELETE FROM `ps_module` WHERE `name` = "mymodule";
```

- Next, delete roles from authorization role table.

  Module installer automatically add CRUD roles for your module. Delete them from `authorization_role` table.
- Install your module again.

**Environment**: PHP7.2, Prestashop v1.7.6.4